# Why is Modelsim displaying "Error: MIF contains illegal character" when I try to simulate?

Tags: simulation, modelsim, quartus

I'm currently designing a MIPS based processors in VHDL using Quartus 20.1 along with Modelsim 2020.1.

I created a MIF file that (hopefully) calculates the GCD of a given number. My MIF file consists of the following:

```
Depth = 256;
Width = 32;
Address_radix = hex;
Data_radix = bin;

%This program will calculate the GCD of the values stored in inport0 and inport1%
%Main :%
%lw $s0, FFF8($zero)%
00:10001100000100001111111111111000;
%lw $s1, FFFC($zero)%
01:10001100000100011111111111111100;

%loop:%
%beq $s1, $s0, Exit_the_Loop%
02:00010010001100000000000000001001;        
%sltu $t0, $s1, $s0%            
03:000000010001000110000101011; 
%bne $t0, $zero, skip%          
04:00010101000000000000000000000111;        
%subu $s1, $s1, $s0%        
05:00000010001100011000000000100011;            
%j loop%            
06:00001000000000000000000000000010;        
%skip:% 
%subu $s0, $s0, $s1%            
07:00000010000100001000100000100011;        
%j loop%            
08:00001000000000000000000000000010;        

%Exit_the_Loop:%
%sw $s0, FFFC($zero)%           
09:10101100000100001111111111111100;        
%End:% 
%j  End%                
0A:00001000000000000000000000001010;        
END;
```

However, everytime I try to simulate my design in modelsim, I get the following error:
"Error: MIF contains illegal character0"
The error message itself is unclear, I understand that I have an illegal character or some kind of syntax error somewhere in my file, but the error message isn't telling me where.
In addition, I've checked my MIF file against others that were working and I see no issue with it off the bat.

Can anyone confirm whether my MIF file has an error somewhere that could be causing this? I'm not sure what else to do.

I tried referencing an example MIF file I keep around for situations like this, but it was no luck.
I also tried googling what could be causing this *specific* error, but also no luck.

Originally, dashes were used instead of percent symbols to represent comments, as I thought that was the issue, but also no bueno.

Comment: I recall the mif format being described in the MDS-80 documentation back in the mid to late '70s, but it really isn't standardized. I'd naively expect a CONTENT delineation after the data radix declaration, followed by  a BEGIN and the whole thing terminated by an END; Only having access to a Quartus II 9.1 alter_mf_components.vhd and altera_mf.vhd I found that that version (from 2000) didn't like your % delimited block comments.  Prefixing those lines with "--" with the CONTENT, BEGIN and END; allowed your mif file to be successfully read using a rom comprised of an altsyncram model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue, it was a foolish oversight on my part. Props to user16145658 for helping resolve it!

The reason why it was showing an error was because: i forgot the "content" and "begin" headers.

Here's the correct MIF file, works as expected!

```
Depth = 256;
Width = 32;
Address_radix = hex;
Data_radix = bin;
CONTENT
BEGIN
-- lw $s0, FFF8($zero)
00:10001100000100001111111111111000;
-- lw $s1, FFFC($zero)
01:10001100000100011111111111111100;
-- beq $s1, $s0, Exit_the_Loop
02:00010010001100000000000000000110;        
-- sltu $t0, $s1, $s0   
03:00000010001100000100000000101011;    
-- bne $t0, $zero, skip
04:00010101000000000000000000000010;        
-- subu $s1, $s1, $s0
05:00000010001100001000100000100011;            
-- j loop           
06:00001000000000000000000000000010;        
-- subu $s0, $s0, $s1               
07:00000010000100011000000000100011;        
-- j loop           
08:00001000000000000000000000000010;        
-- sw $s0, FFFC($zero)      
09:10101100000100001111111111111100;        
-- j  End           
0A:00001000000000000000000000001010;        
END;
```